# Creating meteor project throws error

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm

**The question which was said has the same solution has no solution, so it does not solve my problem.**

I've installed Node, writing `node -v` in cmd returns `v8.10.0`.

Also installed meteor, `meteor --version` returns `Meteor 1.6.1`. After these steps I want to create an app like [here](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/creating-an-app).

So, I wrote:

`meteor create simple-todos`

and I get this error:

> C:\Users\Rares\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:218
>         throw error;
>         ^
>
> Error: Error: Could not install npm dependencies for test-packages:
>   Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c
>   C:\Users\Rares\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\bin\npm.cmd
>   install --production=false npm ERR! Cannot read property 'match' of
>   undefined
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Rares\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-03-27T20_09_26_892Z-debug.log
>   npm ERR! Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Rares\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-03-27T20_09_26_892Z-debug.log
>
> ```
> at Object.error (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:430:11)
> at C:\tools\cli\default-npm-deps.js:36:20
> at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:334:18
> at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
> at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:333:36
> at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
> at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:324:26)
> at Object.install (C:\tools\cli\default-npm-deps.js:27:27)
> at Command.func (C:\tools\cli\commands.js:801:36)
> at C:\tools\cli\main.js:1523:15
> ```

The function from promise_server.js invoked is

```
function tryCatchNextTick(object, method, args) {
  try {
    return method.apply(object, args);
  } catch (error) {
    process.nextTick(function () {
      throw error;
    });
  }
}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stuck on extracting meteor-tool@1.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48783978/stuck-on-extracting-meteor-tool1-6-1)

Comment: so waiting for 30 min will solve the problem? :)

Comment: hhhhhh no it happened once ,then i didn't get that problem again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in my case was to run these steps:

```
meteor npm install 
meteor
```