# Meteor throws errors on initial run

Tags: meteor

I've read multiple questions that are similar to the issue but none of their answers have fixed my problem. Here is a link to the other questions/answers that I've tried.

1. [Creating meteor project throws error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49521627/creating-meteor-project-throws-error)
2. [meteor create project failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49600792/meteor-create-project-failing)

I really appreciate the help determining why meteor does not work on 2 of my machines. It's running fine on my laptop. I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling meteor and node. I'm running command line in admin mode. I'm totally stuck here.

My issue/error is:

```
C:\Users\dbaccus\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.7.0_3\mt-os.window
s.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:218
      throw error;
      ^

Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, symlink 'C:\Users\dbaccus\AppData\Local\.
meteor\packages\babel-compiler\7.1.1\npm\node_modules\@babel\plugin-transform-ob
ject-super' -> 'c:\Users\dbaccus\Documents\GitHub\simple-todos\.meteor\local\.bu
ild441417.build\programs\.build716012.server\npm\node_modules\meteor\babel-compi
ler\node_modules\@babel\plugin-transform-object-super'
    at Object.fs.symlinkSync (fs.js:1014:18)
    at Object.wrapper (C:\tools\fs\files.js:1607:35)
    at symlinkWithOverwrite (C:\tools\fs\files.js:543:11)
    at walk (C:\tools\isobuild\builder.js:526:9)
    at optimisticReaddir.forEach.item (C:\tools\isobuild\builder.js:621:11)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at walk (C:\tools\isobuild\builder.js:532:34)
    at optimisticReaddir.forEach.item (C:\tools\isobuild\builder.js:621:11)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at walk (C:\tools\isobuild\builder.js:532:34)
    at Builder._copyDirectory (C:\tools\isobuild\builder.js:670:5)
    at Builder.copyNodeModulesDirectory (C:\tools\isobuild\builder.js:426:17)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2317:17
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\dbaccus\AppData\Local\.meteor\package
s\meteor-tool\1.7.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscor
e\underscore.js:87:22)
    at JsImage.write (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2276:7)
    at ServerTarget.write (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2548:13)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2701:30
    at Object.keys.forEach.name (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2836:9)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2826:26
    at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:3167:22
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:271:13
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89
:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:264:29
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89
:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:262:18
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89
:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:253:23
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89
:14)
    at Object.capture (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:252:19)
    at bundle (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:3000:31)
    at files.withCache (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2947:32)
    at Object.withCache (C:\tools\fs\files.js:1710:12)
    at Object.exports.bundle (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2947:16)
    at Profile.run (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:579:36)
    at Function.run (C:\tools\tool-env\profile.js:490:12)
    at bundleApp (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:578:34)
    at AppRunner._runOnce (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:622:35)
    at AppRunner._fiber (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:880:28)
    at C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:408:12
```

Comment: Please edit your question to replace the search link by the *real* list of the answers you have tried or thought to be related. Simply because what is shown by the link will change for many reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the question.